# Как вернуть ответ на запрос? чистый PHP

Tags: php, запрос, платежи

Есть самописный платежный шлюз на PHP (просто форма на html + логика на PHP, которая делает запрос по API банка и передает данные в банк). Пример запроса

```
payload = {
    "service_id": "777",
    "order_price": "10",
    "contract_id": "5",
    "contract_date": "2021-03-05",
    "contract_name": "Иванов Иван Иваныч",
    "payer_name": "Иванов Иван Иваныч",
    "payer_phone": "+7(666)666-66-66",
    "payer_email": "example@mail.ru",
    "personal_data_acceptance": "personal_data_acceptance",
    "commission_payment_acceptance": "commission_payment_acceptance"
}
```

После отправки в банк этих данных, возвращается результат об оплате и в лог записывается результат с номером операции от банка.

Хочу сделать так чтоб при запросе с определенного доменного имени отрабатывал скрипт шлюза и возвращал на это доменное имя результат об оплате в виде:

```
payload = {
    "service_id": "777",
    "payment_result" = "true",
    "contract_id": "5",
    "user_id" = "2881488" (будет приходить в запросе от домена)
}
```

Как это сделать на чистом PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить о чистейшем PHP то делается это через PHP Streams и file_get_contents.

Но всё-же рекомендую использовать libcurl.

```php
<?php
$data = json_encode([
    "service_id" => "777",
    "order_price" => "10",
    "contract_id" => "5",
    "contract_date" => "2021-03-05",
    "contract_name" => "Иванов Иван Иваныч",
    "payer_name" => "Иванов Иван Иваныч",
    "payer_phone" => "+7(666)666-66-66",
    "payer_email" => "example@mail.ru",
    "personal_data_acceptance" => "personal_data_acceptance",
    "commission_payment_acceptance" => "commission_payment_acceptance"
]);

$url = 'https://ptsv2.com/t/oz8rh-1637133493/post';

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data,
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```